# Update rows with composite primary key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I want to update every row by increasing 1 on the Ordering field, for every row that has Ordering GREATER OF EQUAL than some value but not for a specific row (IdClass=15,IdContent=9, for example - both are primary keys)

Like

```
UPDATE Content_Class 
    SET Ordering=Ordering+1 
WHERE Ordering>= 4 
AND (IdClass <> 15 AND IdContent <> 9)
```

What happens is that, both (IdClass=15,IdContent=8) and (IdClass=15,IdContent=9) are ignored is this query.

How can I do this with just one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE Content_Class 
SET Ordering=Ordering+1 
WHERE Ordering>=4 
AND NOT(IdClass = 15 AND IdContent = 9)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Content_Class 
    SET Ordering=Ordering+1 
WHERE Ordering>= 4 
AND (IdClass <> 15 OR IdContent <> 9)
```

OR

```
UPDATE Content_Class 
    SET Ordering=Ordering+1 
WHERE Ordering>= 4 
AND IdClass NOT IN (15,9)
```